# Why does removing BehaviourSubject cause my service to delay for 3-4 seconds?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I had earlier created a `BehaviourSubject` and on subscribing it I was making a service call. But, due to the nature of `BehaviorSubject`, there was an unnecessary on the initialisation of the `BehaviouSubject`.  So, on further reading, I changed `BehaviourSubjedct` to `ReplaySubject(1)`.

Now, In the main `@Injectable` class where I have defined the services, there is another service which is independent, that gets delayed once I made the above changes. How do I determine the cause of the issue here?

component.ts

```
constructor(private _subjectService: SubjectService, private _s1: Service1){
    this._s1.Call1();
    this.testFunction();
}

testFunction(){
this._subjectService.GetData().subscribe(res => {
      if (res !== null) {
         this._s1.Call2();  
     }
   }
}
```

SubjectService

```
  // filterSubject = new BehaviorSubject(<KendoRequestVM>{});
  // filterDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject(<KendoRequestVM>{});

   filterSubject = new ReplaySubject<KendoRequestVM>(1);
   filterDataSubject = new ReplaySubject<KendoRequestVM>(1);
```

Here, Call1() is getting called when I use `BehaviouSubject` instead of `ReplaySubject`.

Answer (score 1):

A behavior subject will always return immediately (synchronously even).  A replay subject will only return immediately / synchronously if it has a value.  It's impossible to tell with just the code you've shared because you haven't shared the part that is populating the subjects (e.g. calling `next`) but that seems like the most likely explanation.